# How to create xhtml query strings with Scala?

Tags: xml, xhtml, scala, query-string, lift

How do I create an x(ht)ml-Node containing a href-attribute including a query string without the &s being escaped automatically or runtime error?

```
val text = Text("?key=val&key2=val2")
```

will be escaped and

```
val node = <a href="link?key=val&key2=val2">link</a>
```

throws (in Scala 2.7.5):

```
java.lang.AssertionError
```

The node will be used with the Lift bind() helper method, preferably with AttrBindParam().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
val text = scala.xml.Unparsed("link?key=val&key2=val2")
val node = <a href={text}>link</a>
```

But may be you really mean:

```
val node = <a href="link?key=val&amp;key2=val2">link</a>
```

See [Using Ampersands in Attribute Values (and Elsewhere)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_12) in the `XHTML 1.0` reference.

Answer (score 1):

The following will escape the ampersand:

```
val node = <a href={"link?key=val&key2=val2"}>link</a>
```

Which, arguably, is what you really need.